# Android Studio freezes very often

Tags: macos, android-studio, macbookpro-touch-bar

My Android Studio freezes at least 2 times per day sometimes, even more than dozen times.

I use Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5, but it used to happen also on stable 3.1.

```
About my mac 
 Model Name:    MacBook Pro
 Model Identifier:  MacBookPro13,2
 Processor Name:    Intel Core i5
 Processor Speed:   2.9 GHz
 Number of Processors:  1
```

I have at least 2 projects open, slack and browser with ~6 tabs. Usually, it happens after a build.
I work on 3 displays (2 external connected by USB-C)
It also occurs on my private MacBook 2013.

[edit]
Unfortunately increasing values in `studio.vmotipons` from

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
```

to

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

doesn't solve the issue.

My current memory usage when a freeze occurred
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer here but try increasing memory allocated for Studio
http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/01/19/How-to-increase-Android-studio-memory-limit-in-Mac/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me on Ubuntu as well. It's really painful. I can't take it any more. Going back to beta 4 until they say something or come out with another update of some kind.

Comment: It used to happen for me even on the stable 3.1, to be fair.